# Why does QUOTE_IDENT doubles the embedded quotation mark

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, quotation-marks

The `Redshift` [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_QUOTE_IDENT.html) for the `QUOTE_IDENT` function says

> The QUOTE_IDENT function returns the specified string as a string in double quotation marks so that it can be used as an identifier in a SQL statement. Appropriately doubles any embedded double quotation marks.

I understand the first part about surrounding a string with double quotation marks. But when is it `appropriate` to double embedded quotation marks? Why is that useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when is it appropriate to double embedded quotation marks? Why is that useful?

It's always appropriate. It's useful because the output of `QUOTE_IDENT` is often embedded into a larger string. As such, you then have a quoted string inside the larger string and you detect the end of such a string by finding a *single* double quote. I.e. assume we pass `AB"CD` to `QUOTE_IDENT`. We receive back `"AB""CD"`. We then embed that into:

```
SELECT "AB""CD" FROM Foo
```

And when that's parsed later, we find a *single* identifier `AB"CD` in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Why would the double quotation marks in the middle of the string be parsed as a single quotation mark?

Comment: @Forever - because that's a common convention in parsing strings that SQL has adopted; when you have some form of delimiter and need to have a way to embed that delimiter within a delimited string, you double the delimiters.

Comment: @Forever - of course, other languages/contexts use other conventions. E.g. to embed a quote in a string in python you'd use a backslash escape (`\"`).